# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have encountered an error while linking my component to the store.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'errorMessage' of undefined

```
Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]

  37 | const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
> 38 |   errorMessage: state.errorRedux.errorMessage,
  39 |   error: state.errorRedux.error,
  40 | })
```

I cannot put my finger on what the issue is. It shouldn't be listening for the error as I've chosen to render the message conditionally.

1. I have tried setting `errorMessage: string | undefined | null` to no success.
2. I tried `errorMessage: "[INTERFACE"]` to no success.
3. I tried `errorMessage?: string`
   I think the problem could lie somewhere in extending the ErrorHandlerProps interface but I have already extended the mapStateToProps?

```
import { Dispatch, Action } from "redux"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { AppState } from "reducers"
import { showError } from "data/error_handler"

class ErrorHandler extends React.Component<
  ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>
> {
  public render() {
    const { onShowError, error, errorMessage } = this.props

    let showTheError =
      this.props.error === true ? (
        <Snackbar
          open={error}
          message={errorMessage}
          autoHideDuration={5000}
        />
      ) : null

    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton onClick={onShowError} label="Toggle ErrorHandler" />
        {showTheError}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  errorMessage: state.errorRedux.errorMessage,
  error: state.errorRedux.error,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
  return {
    onShowError: () => dispatch(showError()),
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ErrorHandler)
```

`data/interfaces.ts`

```
export interface ErrorHandlerProps {
  error: boolean
  errorMessage: string
}
```

`data/reducer.ts`

```
import { ErrorHandlerProps, ActionTypes } from "./"

const initialState: ErrorHandlerProps = {
  error: false,
  errorMessage: "",
}

export default (
  state: ErrorHandlerProps = initialState,
  action: ActionTypes
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SHOW_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

`reducers.ts`

```
import { reducer as errorHandler, ErrorHandlerProps } from "data/error_handler"

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  errorHandler
} as any)

export type AppState = {
  errorRedux: ErrorHandlerProps
}
```

`store.ts`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux"
import { routerMiddleware } from "react-router-redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import rootReducer, { AppState } from "reducers"

const initialState = {}
const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)]
const composedEnhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers)

export default store
export const getState = () => store.getState() as AppState
```

Comment: why are you manually importing your state through this `import { AppState } from "reducers"`  ... I guess it's the job of `mapStateToProps`

Comment: The { AppState } import is a combination of all interfaces I use in my project. ```export type AppState = {   example: ExampleModel, post: PostModel, errorRedux: ErrorHandlerProps }```

Comment: I apologize ... I'm zero-experience in typescript

Comment: No need to apologize. I'm fairly new in TypeScript myself. Thank you for taking the time to help

Comment: looks like the reducer `errorRedux` is not there, amongst your reducers, so afaik nothing to do with Typescript. Can you share how you setup the reducers in redux ?

Comment: @stilllife Yes, silly me. Just edited the question. It makes sense that I'm calling on the variable type rather than the initialState. I may have taken for granted that React would take care of it.

Comment: It still doesn't show how you configure the redux store. I see the `combineReducers` but there is no `errorRedux` in there. Somewhere you are probably passing to a redux Provider an object called `store`, this store takes an object of reducers, among those you need to have `errorRedux`. The typing is just... typing :)

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier if we can see how you created your store.

Usually this issue happens when you use `combineReducers`, because it creates an object of reducers and that is what `mapStateToProps` receives, instead of the state directly.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import testReducer from "./reducer";
import testReducer2 from "./reducer2";

// ----
// using combine reducers will make the state in mapStateToProps to be an object of all the reducers combined, so you have to access it like state.testReducer.value or state.testReducer2.value

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  testReducer,
  testReducer2
});
// ----

// ----
// while passing a reducer directly will not have the same effect and the state will be accessible like state.value in mapStateToProps

const rootReducer = testReducer;
// ----

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

See the following sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/k3ojkqxy57

Comment: Yeah, apologies for not referencing the store. When asking for help on React / Redux I feel guilty for code dumping so many files and code. I edited my question to include the store file. It is exported as AppState. Perhaps I should be importing directly from the store

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
   errorMessage: state.getIn(['errorRedux', 'errorMessage'], 'default value here'),
   error: state.getIn(['errorRedux', 'error'], ], 'default value here'),
})
```

Comment: I tried it. No success : / Thanks for teaching me about getIn though